# Downgrading XIB from Xcode 5 to Xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, ios7, xib, xcode5

I upgraded Xcode 4.6.2 to Xcode 5. My existing project's xib files were upgraded to Xcode 5. I have tried to revert them back to Xcode 4.6 (in File Inspector, Interface Builder Document, "Opens in: Xcode 4.6"), but after rebuilding the project and running it on the device (iOS 7), the interface on the device is still Xcode 5 (the app buttons and toolbar are the new iOS 7 style).

[image: Xcode 5 File Inspector]

How can I revert the interface to look like before (pre iOS 7.0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That pop up simply defines the format of the XIB file itself.  It does nothing to affect the interface at runtime.

In order to keep the iOS 6 *look* of your app, you'd have to compile with the iOS 6 SDK, which means you'd have to keep using Xcode 4.6.3.  (There are people out there who would say that you could copy the iOS 6 SDK into Xcode 5, but that results in an unsupported configuration of Xcode and is definitely *not* recommended)

Comment: Thanks Dave, I will try that. I don't know why Xcode 5 offers to revert to the old xib interface, if it does not support building the app with that old interface. Does it mean that the project needs to be build and deployed separately for iOS6 (with older interface) and iOS7 (with newer interface)?

Comment: @kzia that's so you can share xib files between developers who have different versions of Xcode (for example, one using Xcode 5 and one using Xcode 4).

Comment: Does it mean that the project needs to be built and deployed separately for iOS6 (with older interface) and iOS7 (with newer interface)?

Comment: @kzia no, you should be building it all in Xcode 5.  When you run an app built against iOS 7 on an iOS 6 device, it will obviously look like iOS 6.

Comment: @DaveDeLong however, under iOS 7 if you want your app to look the same in Xcode 5 as it did in Xcode 4, you *do* have to keep separate projects, unless there is a way to tell Xcode 5 to build the app the same way Xcode 4 did. This *should* be a build setting somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Reid if you want to have your app look like iOS 6 when running on iOS 7, then you would have to compile your project with Xcode 4.6.3.  Having "separate projects" means you would have to have two different versions of the app on the store, which you don't want.

Comment: @Dave The separate projects was for a "version 2" of an app versus a "version 1" of an app already in the app store that needs to be maintained. If we could build it just like Xcode 4, we could keep it as separate targets in one project. But we can't, so separate projects it is.. :-/